# Supposedly easy trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I've created a trigger which is to block inserted records with a date already existing in a table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SpecialOffers_Insert]
ON [dbo].[SpecialOffers]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE SPO_DateFrom IN (SELECT SPO_DateFrom FROM dbo.SpecialOffers))
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Error. ', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

It is added to a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SpecialOffers](
[SPO_SpoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SPO_DateFrom] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[SPO_DateTo] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

The table is empty but when trying to insert such record:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SpecialOffers (SPO_DateFrom, SPO_DateTo) VALUES ('2015-01-15','2015-01-15')
```

I got the Error from the trigger. How should I modify the trigger not to get the error?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? Triggers can run BEFORE insert (before records actually added to table) or AFTER insert (when records already added to table and visible to you by SELECT).

Comment: Why not just apply a unique constraint?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to block inserted records with date already existing in a table, you don't need a trigger - just create a unique constraint on the date field:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SpecialOffers]
ADD CONSTRAINT SpecialOffersUQ UNIQUE (SPO_DateFrom)
```

Comment: Than you for the quick answer but the actual goal is to check the periods between SPO_DateFrom and SPO_DateTo so that inserted period doesn't overlap with existsing ones, so it has to be in a trigger. Any idea how what to do with the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a trigger to prevent overlaps, why didn't you say so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SpecialOffers](
  [SPO_SpoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [SPO_DateFrom] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [SPO_DateTo] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  constraint CK_SO_NoTimeTravel CHECK (SPO_DateFrom <= SPO_DateTo)
)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER NoOverlaps
on dbo.SpecialOffers
after insert,update
as
    set nocount on
    if exists (
        select *
        from dbo.SpecialOffers so1
                inner join
            dbo.SpecialOffers so2
                on
                    so1.SPO_DateFrom < so2.SPO_DateTo and
                    so2.SPO_DateFrom < so1.SPO_DateTo and
                    so1.SPO_SpoId != so2.SPO_SpoId
                inner join
            inserted i
                on
                    so1.SPO_SpoId = i.SPO_SpoId
        )
    begin
        RAISERROR('No overlaps',16,1)
        ROLLBACK
    end
```

Examples:

```
--Works
INSERT INTO SpecialOffers (SPO_DateFrom,SPO_DateTo)
values ('20010101','20011231')
GO
--Fails (Trigger)
INSERT INTO SpecialOffers (SPO_DateFrom,SPO_DateTo)
values ('20010101','20011231')
GO
--Fails (Constraint)
INSERT INTO SpecialOffers (SPO_DateFrom,SPO_DateTo)
values ('20011231','20010101')
GO
--Fails (Trigger)
INSERT INTO SpecialOffers (SPO_DateFrom,SPO_DateTo)
values ('20020101','20021231'),
       ('20020701','20030630')
```

I also added a check constraint so that I didn't have to deal with nonsense data in the trigger.

You might have to change swap some of the `<`s for `<=`s or vice-versa, depending on what definition of intervals you want to use (i.e. are `DateFrom` and `DateTo` meant to be *inclusive* or *exclusive* endpoints for the interval they're describing?)

Comment: Thank you, Damien. I'll be testing that in a minute.

Comment: Works perfect. Only periods overlaping conditions needed some correction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the trigger runs in the transaction context of the SQL statement that fired it, after this `INSERT`, there **will be** a row in your table `dbo.SpecialOffers` with the `SPO_DateFrom` values you've just inserted and the `SELECT` from the table will succeed ...

Therefore, the trigger will assume that there's already been a value - and it throws the error (as designed).

You *could* rewrite the trigger to not look at the newly inserted rows, but anything else - but as others have pointed out, a `UNIQUE` constraint does that much more simply

Comment: 1. Constraint - will it help with periods overlaping? 2. Trigger excluding newly added record - is there any special syntax for that or should I simply put NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE ...)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the rows you found are actually NOT the ones you have just inserted. Change the line

```
IF EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM inserted 
      WHERE SPO_DateFrom IN (
          SELECT SPO_DateFrom 
          FROM dbo.SpecialOffers)
      )
```

To

```
IF EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM inserted a
      WHERE SPO_DateFrom IN (
          SELECT SPO_DateFrom 
          FROM dbo.SpecialOffers b 
          WHERE a.SPO_SpoId <> b.SPO_SpoId)
      )
```